# How do I query for a variable attribute of a django model?

Tags: django, django-models

I know I can use `getattr(mymodel, myvar)` to get a variable attribute from a model. However, this doesn't work if I want to also be able to get attributes from related models using django's double underscore notation.

How would I accomplish something like the following?

```
mymodel.get('relation__relation_attr')
```

Thanks!

Comment: What about `mymodel.relation.relation_attr'`?

Comment: I only get the attribute to be queried as a string, and I want my code to be flexible enough to handle both attributes on the model and on related models.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Reduce](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce) is your friend:

```
#we take a model:
m=Material.objects.all()[0]

#now I navigate to some attr:
m.uf.mp.nom

#we get:
u'Programació multimèdia i dispositius mòbils'

#I write attr path as string:
str="uf__mp__nom"

#I invoke reduce to get attr value through path: 
reduce( getattr, [ m ] + str.split("__" ) )

#we get same result, txan txan!!
u'Programació multimèdia i dispositius mòbils'
```

Another example:

```
>>> m.uf.mp.cicle.nom
u'Desenvolupament d aplicacions multiplataforma'
>>> 
>>> str="uf__mp__cicle__nom"
>>> 
>>> reduce( getattr, [ m ] + str.split("__" ) )
u'Desenvolupament d aplicacions multiplataforma'
```

write your own function to encapsulate it.

Comment: Great, didn't know about the reduce method, but it's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!